# jquery/js hide submit button if div has specific style

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I would be grateful for could help. I try to hide submit button when specific error message is visible, show the submit button when the message is gone. I need to use data-id attribute.

It looks like my code is works when I use google chrome console but only at once. It's doesn't work at all when I include this into the website.

Sorry if I didn't describe this perfectly. This is my first post so I hope you will be understandable.

```
if($('div[data-id="opce_error"]').css('display') === 'none') {
     $(".wpcf7-submit").show();
  }
  if($('div[data-id="opce_error"]').css('display') === 'block') {
     $(".wpcf7-submit").hide();
  }
```

```
<div data-id="opce_error" data-orig_data_id="opce_error" data-class="wpcf7cf_group" class="" style="display: block;">
<label class="assets-error">Submit button is hidden</label>
</div>
```

Comment: you are checking that condition on click of some button ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. How can I do that?

Comment: I mean to say where did you put that jquery code? and how does that get called ?Can you add demo code ?

Comment: It's added this to the footer. Hm I could try to show this to you on demo.

Answer (score 0):

you use this inside a onReady function of jQuery? The html is still render? Maybe can you use pastebin, or similar tool for give us a example demo?

Comment: I tried use  $(document).ready(function() but it's still the same. Code seems to work (on google console) but for some reason it doesn't recognize changes in HTML. 

Maybe this will be helpful. Not sure. https://codepen.io/georgepennet/pen/XWmGGNJ

it's not entire code but you can see that i's lot loading by itself

Comment: i see the codepen and changing the display of the errore cause a button appear&disappear... so. i not understand your requirements...